# Cómo clonar y liberar los recursos de una imagen correctamente en c#

Tags: c#, imagen, memoria

Quisiera saber cómo clonar y liberar los recursos de una imagen correctamente.
Tengo una aplicación donde se editan listas de imágenes que se visualizan en un ListView. La lista de imágenes se gestiona en una clase que denomino FicheroLogos:

```
public class FicheroLogos : ICloneable
{
    public string trayectoriaYnombre = "";
    public string etiquetaDelSubmenu = "";
    public string urlIcono = "";
    public bool iconoModificado = false; // Se usa para comprobar si hay que recargar la imagen del menú contextual de editar canales.
    public Image icono = null;
    public List<Logo> listaDeLogos = new List<Logo>();
    public int contadorDeErrores;

    public object Clone()
    {
        var ficheroLogoTemp = (FicheroLogos)this.MemberwiseClone();
        if (ficheroLogoTemp.listaDeLogos != null)
        {
            var listaLogoTemp = ficheroLogoTemp.listaDeLogos.Select(x => x.Clone() as Logo);
            var copiaListaLogo = new List<Logo>(listaLogoTemp);
            ficheroLogoTemp.listaDeLogos = copiaListaLogo;
        }
        return ficheroLogoTemp;
    }
}
```

La clase Logo es:

```
public class Logo : ICloneable
{
    public string nombre;
    public string urlLogo;
    public Image imagen;
    public string grupo = "";
    public bool error = false;

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

La propiedad OwnerDraw del ListView es true, porque el control lo dibujo mediante el código.
La asignación de las imágenes al ListView la realizo llamado al Clone() de la imagen, que creo que es lo correcto para poder seguir usando el objeto **ficheroLogosAeditar** (que es de la clase FicheroLogo) si a posteriori borro el ListView:

```
ListViewLogosAeditar.BeginUpdate();

for (int i = 0; i < ficheroLogosAeditar.listaDeLogos.Count; i++)
{
    var elemento = ficheroLogosAeditar.listaDeLogos.ElementAt(i);
    ImagenListViewItem item = new ImagenListViewItem
    {
        ToolTipText = "texto",
        Bitmap = (Bitmap)RedimensionarImagen((Image)elemento.imagen.Clone(), anchoLogoAeditar, altoLogoAeditar)
    };

    ListViewLogosAeditar.Items.Add(item);
}

ListViewLogosAeditar.EndUpdate();
```

Hay momentos en la aplicación, como puede ser cargar otro FicheroLogos, crear uno nuevo, o cerrar el formulario donde está el ListView, que llamo a **ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar()** para borrar el ListView:

```
private void ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar()
{
    foreach (var item in ListViewLogosAeditar.Items)
        ((ImagenListViewItem)item).Bitmap.Dispose();

    ListViewLogosAeditar.Items.Clear();
}
```

Lo que no se porque sucede es que si después de llamar a ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar() intento acceder a las imágenes de ficheroLogosAeditar, algunas de ellas son inaccesibles, o sea que se genera un error. Lo que sucede es que al mismo tiempo que se libera memoria al llamar a Dispose() de los ítems del ListView en ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar(), también se libera la memoria de algunas de las imágenes de ficheroLogosAeditar.

Al depurar en Visual Studio las iteraciones del bucle de ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar() se ve en la inspección del objeto ficheroLogosAeditar que en algunas de las imágenes de listaDeLogos, sus componentes pasan inmediatamente todos a color rojo, o sea que ya no son accesibles.

He probado a clonar el FicheroLogos antes de llamar a ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar(), porque el  formulario que muestra al formulario del ListView tiene que acceder a un objeto FicheroLogos del formulario del ListView, pero como al cerrar el formulario del ListView también llamo a ClearTodosLosLogosAEditar() para liberar la memoria, pues algunas imágenes del objeto FicheroLogos se corrompen.

```
FicheroLogos ficheroNuevo = (FicheroLogos)ficheroLogosAeditar.Clone();
```

Las imágenes que tiene el objeto FicheroLogos son imágenes que se descargan de internet y hay veces que se crean ficheros de más de 5000 imágenes. Es decir, si se visualizan un par de ficheros en el ListView llegan a consumir cerca o más de 10 Gigas de la RAM.

Resumiendo, si libero la memoria, se producen errores por intentar acceder a imágenes que “no existen”, y si no libero la memoria, si puedo acceder a las imágenes, pero la aplicación no es nada eficiente, consume toda la memoria RAM en un par de visualizaciones.

Bueno pues, haber si alguien puede indicarme que está sucediendo y como generar un código más eficiente. Gracias.

Publico el código de RediemnsionarImagen():

```
private Image RedimensionarImagen(Image imagenAredimensionar, int anchoLogo, int altoLogo)
{
    int nuevoAncho;
    int nuevoAlto;
    float proporcionAltura;
    float proporcionAnchura;
    Size size;

    if (imagenAredimensionar.Height <= altoLogo && imagenAredimensionar.Width <= anchoLogo) return imagenAredimensionar;

    try
    {
        proporcionAltura = altoLogo * 100 / (float)imagenAredimensionar.Height;
        proporcionAnchura = anchoLogo * 100 / (float)imagenAredimensionar.Width;

        if (proporcionAltura < proporcionAnchura)
        {
            nuevoAncho = (int)(imagenAredimensionar.Width * proporcionAltura) / 100;
            size = new Size(nuevoAncho, altoLogo);
        }
        else
        {
            nuevoAlto = (int)(imagenAredimensionar.Height * proporcionAnchura) / 100;
            size = new Size(anchoLogo, nuevoAlto);
        }

        return (Image)(new Bitmap(imagenAredimensionar, size));
    }
    catch
    {
        Image imagenVacio = new Bitmap(anchoLogo, altoLogo);
        return imagenVacio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Por las dudas publica el código de `RedimensionarImagen`. Yo creo que tienes el [Problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3361/301324), tu querías hacer algo y tu solución pasó por clonar y hacer dispose y esto no te resultó.  Mencionas que tienes problemas de memoria, pero al parecer mantienes 2 listas de imagines (ficheroLogosAeditar y ListViewLogosAeditar)  y si solo tuvieras reducirías a la mitad el gasto de memoria

Comment: Lo que sucede es que el formulario del ListView recibe como parametro un objeto FicheroLogos y además ha de retornar también un objeto de esta clase.
Publico el código de RediemnsionarImagen():

Comment: Si ocuparas Binding me parece que con una Lista tienes. Además lo que veo es que RedimensionarImagen crea una nueva imagen entonces no es necesario clonarla, por lo que tiendo a pensar que tu error no pasa por el tema de `Referencia`, es decir que borras en un lado y te lo borra en otro también. Podrías contar un poco más de que se trata la aplicación, me queda claro que tienes una lista de imágenes, pero tú dices que la editan, editan la imagen o los datos que la acompañan???? Otra cosa que tengo duda es porque haces `.Items.Clear()`, esto es porque quieres recargar la lista??

Comment: Otra cosa, esto es WPF, WinForm, UWP?????

Comment: Es un formulario WinForm

Comment: lo de .Items.Clear() es porque quiero cargar otra lista

Comment: No, las imagens no se editan, lo que se edita es el FicheroLogos, es decir se puede sustituir su icono, se puede modificar el contador de errores y de puede editar la lista de las imagenes, es decir añadir imagenes, eliminarlas, sustituirlas... pero internamente la imagenes no se modifican.

Comment: Le he dado varias vueltas a tu problema, pero siempre termino con más dudas. Por ejemplo, las imágenes están en disco??? Porque perfectamente podrías guardar en tu objeto la ruta de la imagen, no la imagen misma. Lo cual consume mucho menos recursos

Comment: No, las imagenes no están en local, son imagens de internet. Lo que la aplicacion hace es leer un fichero de texto de texto con url's de imagenes y se descargan.

Comment: Yussef, puedo intentar hacer algo de lo que me has dicho para evitar clonaciones , pero las estoy haciendo porque entiendo que si tengo un objeto de tipo FicheroLogos con una serie de imagenes y las clono al llamar a RedimensionarImagen, en un objeto ListView que es de una clase distinta, es precisamente para evitar que se borren las imagenes del objeto FicheroLogos al liberar la memoria del ListView al llamar a Dispose. No entiendo porque al hacer Dispose de las imagenes, que son clonadas, del ListView, tambien se boran algunas del FicheroLogos.